# Group pandas dataframe by value in one of several columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> ex = pd.DataFrame(
        {'from_id': [1, 2, 3], 'to_id': [2, 3, 1], 'duration': [5.0, 10.0, 15.0]}
    )

   from_id  to_id  duration
0        1      2       5.0
1        2      3      10.0
2        3      1      15.0
```

I'd like to access a sub-dataframe (or group) for each id, each containing all rows where either the from_id or the to_id is equal to that value. Here "duration" is just some other piece of data not being grouped by. Desired output would be

```
   from_id  to_id  duration
0        1      2       5.0
2        3      1      15.0

   from_id  to_id  duration
0        1      2       5.0
1        2      3      10.0

   from_id  to_id  duration
1        2      3      10.0
2        3      1      15.0
```

or similar. Is there a clean way to do this? Thanks!

Edit: An answer below suggests a way to grab all relevant rows given an ID. This does work, but ideally I'm looking to do this using a groupby expression, without first having to go through and create a separate array of unique IDs. And/or looking to maintain some sort of index from an id to the rows corresponding to it. New to pandas so open to ideas.

Answer (score 1):

```
ex[(ex['from_id']==id) | (ex['to_id']==id)]
```

You can simply do this for each `id` using boolean indexing. Idea is to if any of this condition is true it is part of my dataframe.

Comment: What does the `^` do here?

Comment: @Zero XOR of boolean values.

Comment: @Zero it would have failed for more than 2 column conditions...`|` is the one we are looking for here.

Comment: XOR is a logic gate right?

Comment: I'm looking to iterate through *all* ids in either column, ideally using a groupby-style expression. I could do what you describe by first compiling an iterable of unique IDs, I suppose. So thank you. I'm going to edit the question in the hopes of a slightly more precise answer.